# How to do experiments on bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: privacy

I come up with a protocol that can enhance the privacy of bitcoin. I want to do some simple experiments on the bitcoin blockchain. However, doing experiments on the real bitcoin blockchain seems expensive and unrealistic. Is there any way to simulate a bitcoin blockchain so that I can do an experiment on it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use other chains:

1. Regtest
2. Testnet
3. Signet